# Join two RDDs then group by another column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have 2 RDDs with the the first having the format `Code: string, Name: string` and rdd2's format is `Code: string, Year: string, Delay: float`

```
rdd1 = [('a', 'name1'), ('b', 'name2')]
rdd2 = [('a', '2000', 1.25), ('a', '2000', 2.0), ('b', '2010', -1.0)]
```

I want to perform a join (on `code`) so that I can group the data by `name` in order to do aggregates like count, average, minimum and maximum on `delay`.

I tried to flatten the values after performing a join like so:

```
joined = rdd1.join(rdd2).map(lambda (keys, values): (keys,) + values)
```

but it came up with error: missing 1 required positional argument.

My join result also only shows `[('code', ('name', 'year'))]` and doesn't include the delay values. How should I solve this?

Comment: Is this for learning purposes? Why not use DataFrames?

Comment: @AmitSingh yep i want to compare run time for dataframe and rdd

Comment: DataFrames are executed using RDDs internally so unless you write the most optimized RDD code, DataFrames should be faster since they are optimized a lot by Spark. But yeah, go ahead and learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work in Python 3.x because support for Tuple Parameter Unpacking ([PEP-3113](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)) was removed. Hence the TypeError.

Pair RDD joins work as key-value where

> (a,b) joined (a, c) will give you (a, (b,c))

So, one way to make it work is this:

```py
joined = rdd1.join(rdd2.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1:])))
joined.map(lambda x: (x[0],)+ (x[1][0],) + x[1][1]).collect()
# Output
# [('b', 'name2', '2010', -1.0),
# ('a', 'name1', '2000', 1.25),
# ('a', 'name1', '2000', 2.0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `rdd2` is in the form of `(key, value)` before joining. Otherwise the elements after the second will be discarded.

```
rdd3 = rdd1.join(rdd2.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], x[2]))))

rdd3.collect()
# [('b', ('name2', ('2010', -1.0))), ('a', ('name1', ('2000', 1.25))), ('a', ('name1', ('2000', 2.0)))]
```

If you want to remove the nested structures, you can add one more `mapValues`:

```
rdd3 = rdd1.join(rdd2.map(lambda x: (x[0], (x[1], x[2])))).mapValues(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][0], x[1][1]))

rdd3.collect()
# [('b', ('name2', '2010', -1.0)), ('a', ('name1', '2000', 1.25)), ('a', ('name1', '2000', 2.0))]
```